How can I check if a certain function overload is invalid?
I am making a type erased class TypeErased using std::variant, that could be an integer, a complex number, a vector, or an error.
While I am making the addition operator (which uses std::visit), I have come into a problem that I don't want certain types to be added together, and it seems very impractical to create overloads for every single unwanted combination.
For example, it should be able to add an integer with a complex number, but not a vector and an integer. To do this, I have tried to use SFINAE (I believe) to create a struct that can tell if a function overload exists:
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

void print(int) {}

template<auto FuncPtr, typename ...Args>
struct FuncExists
{
  template<typename = decltype(FuncPtr(std::declval<Args>()...))>
  constexpr static std::true_type test(int);
  constexpr static std::false_type test(...);

  constexpr static bool value = decltype(test(0))::value;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout<<"print string exists: "<<FuncExists<print, std::string>().value;
}

I expected that it would be able to tell whether it was valid or not, but whenever I try to test it on something that shouldn't work, a compiler error is produced. When I try to pass std::string:
error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' to 'int' in argument passing
12 |   constexpr static auto test(int) -> decltype(FuncPtr(std::declval<Args>()...),        std::true_type());

Why does this not work, and how could I change it to make it work?
For clarity, I am trying to see if a certain overload exists for ANY function (like operator+, sin etc). So if I try to add a variant with an integer and a variant with a vector, it can throw an exception

Do you want the overload to not compile, or would it be acceptable for it to do something (e.g a no-op, or just return one argument) and just not be used?

you talk about adding, put then you show code for a print method. Do you want to check arbitrary functions or just test if a + b is valid for certain type of a and b ?

I will clarify this in the question

also, I want to check if any function overload exists for any function, like operator+, sin, etc, with any amount of overloads or parameters

Can you use C++20?

By the time you have a function pointer, overload resolution (though perhaps trivial) has already happened.  The usual trick is to use lambdas (possibly with decltype, especially before C++20), but that’s quite different from what you have so far.

(I can use c++20) I see, I have done some some research on this, but regardless I am still getting unwanted compiler error messages :(

SFINAE happens only on "direct" context.
Here, template are fixed by class, and it becomes an hard error.
As you have C++20, you might use requires:
template <typename T>
concept is_printable = requires(T t) { print(t); };

Demo

The code in the op is an xy problem. They're really looking to see if a binary function exists for two possibly different types. Edit, I guess it's both unary (sin(x)) and binary

@AndyG: Similar answer: template <typename T, typename U> concept is_some_func_possible = requires(T t, U u) { some_func(t, u); };.

I tried to show example with + (with mixed types), but int is not addable to std::complex :-/

Given OP's design constraints (fixed-type variant) it might make sense to write out explicit visitor overloads for the operations they are interested in.

And given that they're interested in these ops for only a subset of types combos held within the variant, the result type of their operation needs to be different than the result type of the wrapped operation (to account for incompatible types), which leads to e.g., another variant. Unless they want to throw, but I get the impression OP is playing with FP.

You can add double and complex<double>

Hello OP here, so this means that I have to manually to this for all operations (sin cos sqrt plus etc)?

In addition, I have a question. Is there is no general way to test if a function overload exists? It seems like a fairly simple task for the compiler imo.

Either with concept/traits, or "inlined" where you need it.

ok, kinda disappointing lol thanks for the answer either way :D

You cannot pass "overload set", so you have to use MACRO to pass "name", or wrap the overload set into a  functor (lambda for example: [](auto...args)->sin(args...){ return sin(args...); }.

With requires, detect idiom is just one line, and no longer a whole struct to copy paste ;-)

Thanks dude, now I am gonna have to find out about these concepts. They seem kinda cool
